# C# fix chart size

Tags: c#

I'm creating an application which plots data from a serial port. My problem is that sometimes chart size increases when values go below the X axis and, as a result, some values on X axis disappear.

I've set min and max Y axis value, so I wonder how it is possible for the horizontal axis to moves gently downward for a while and then disappear - possibly due to a lack of space?.

It occurs only for first and last label, and sometimes the last grid line disappears too.

Here is piece of code which generate chart values:

```
    int minStress = -200, maxStress=200;
    double maxTime=20.0, minTime=0.0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Stress = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        label6.Text = Stress;
        StressChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minTime;
        StressChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxTime;
        StressChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        StressChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        this.StressChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY((minTime + maxTime) / 2, Stress);
        minTime=minTime + TimerInt_2/1000;
        maxTime=maxTime + TimerInt_2/1000;
        serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();

    }
    private void cmbTimerInt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerInt = int.Parse(cmbTimerInt.Text);
        TimerInt_2=double.Parse(cmbTimerInt.Text);
        timer1.Interval = TimerInt;
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            minStress = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch { }
        if (minStress < maxStress)
        {
            StressChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = minStress;
        }
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            maxStress = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        }
        catch { }
        if (maxStress > minStress)
        {
            StressChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maxStress;
        }
    }
```

Here is code which sets chart properties:

```
            chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0.0";
        chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
        this.StressChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        legend1.Name = "Legend1";
        this.StressChart.Legends.Add(legend1);
        this.StressChart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(225, 12);
        this.StressChart.Name = "StressChart";
        series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
        series1.Legend = "Legend1";
        series1.Name = "Series1";
        this.StressChart.Series.Add(series1);
        this.StressChart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1175, 426);
        this.StressChart.TabIndex = 5;
        this.StressChart.Text = "chart1";
        chartArea1.AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = 0;
        chartArea1.AxisY.LabelAutoFitStyle = 0;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Size = 0;
        chartArea1.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
        chartArea1.AxisY.IsMarginVisible = true;
```

[image: image of chart]

Comment: Can you give us some code, in order to know what you have done, so far?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: You can set/control the minimum&maximum values of each axis.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of such behaviour was decimal places number of X axis labels. Solution is to round these values down to one decimal place.

```
minTime = Math.Round(minTime,1) + Math.Round(TimerInt_2/1000,1);
maxTime = Math.Round(maxTime,1) + Math.Round(TimerInt_2/1000,1);
```